# Drupal 7: Multiple pages for one node

Tags: drupal-7

We list events on our Drupal 7 site, but we'd like our users to be able to register for these events via a simple form. We're using Pathauto to generate URL aliases for events using the following pattern: `events/[node:title]`. We would like to have another page with the alias `events/register/[node:title]` which would present the registration form. We would also like to use tpl.php files for creating the templates, like we do for the rest of the site.

Any ideas on how we might accomplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [Signup module](http://drupal.org/project/signup). It's still in development, but over 7000 sites are using it:

Comment: I'd prefer a more generic solution to this problem so that we can create multiple pages per node for things beside registrable items. But if this works, I'll change the title and mark this as the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would put a register button on the event/ page via the node.tpl.php file. If all your nodes are not registerable, then you can check the node by getting the $nid with $node->nid and run a db_query on the url_alias table to see if current node qualifies.

```
<?php
$nid = $node->nid;
$result = db_query('SELECT alias FROM {url_alias} WHERE source = :source,
  array(':source' => 'node/'.$nid));
foreach ($result as $r) {
  $alias = $r->alias;
}
if (strpos($alias, 'events')) {
  ?> <input... or <button...
```

Have your register button redirect to events/register/$node->title page and make sure you pass the node.  There's a few different ways to go from here.  If you have questions about this part open another thread.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I already have the button in place. What I really need help with is how to create a register page for each event. In other words, I need to create two pages that use different templates and have different aliases but point the same node (as the title of this post states). Thanks.